# jQuery fileTree: passing 'file' as parameter

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand somebody else's code and struggling a little. They are using the jquery fileTree plugin, which provides an interactive file tree on the browser. In this case, the files represent images that have been uploaded to the server.

The code they are using is below. When the user clicks on a file in the file tree, the relevant image is displayed in the `#preview` img element. This line works fine. However, the second line in this function, starting with `$('#info')`, is something that I have inserted myself, and it is not working. I am trying to get the button with id `#info` to change what happens when it is pressed. I want it to call the `Image` controller, with action `Info`, and passing the parameter `image_id`. I want `image_id` to be assigned to the same `file` variable that is used in the `$('#fileTree')` line. I get the following error when I hover the cursor above my new line: `The name 'file' does not exist in the current context.`

Can anybody with any experience with the fileTree plugin explain to me what exactly the `file` variable is, and why it is not allowing me to send it as a parameter as I have attempted above? Why is it allowed in the first line `('#preview')`, but not the second line `('#info')`?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateTree()
    {
        $('#filetree').fileTree(
            {root: '', script: '@Url.Action("Index", "Folder")'},
            function (file)
            {
                $('#preview').attr('src', '@Url.Action("GetImage", "Image")?width=640&drawLabels=true&id=' + file);
                $('#info').attr('value', file).attr('onclick', "location.href='@Url.Action("Info", "Image", new { image_id = file })'");
            }
        );
    }
    updateTree();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate why it doesn't work with Razor. For some reason, which is hard to debug remotely, Razor is not interpreting your javascript variable correctly. Check your HTML.